# Duplicate function same row key

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, antd

I'm creating a duplicate function but getting error below. I'm using Table component using AntDesign. How can I make it unique?

> Encountered two children with the same key, `0`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Here's my code

```
const duplicateEmployeeRow = async key => {
  let duplicateEmployeeSource = [...isEmployeeData];

  let duplicateItem = duplicateEmployeeSource.find(item => item.key == key);

  duplicateEmployeeSource.push(duplicateItem);
  setEmployeeData(duplicateEmployeeSource);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any context, how keys are generated etc, you can generate a unique key with [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) or I guess just assign the length of the prev array.

Note that the next code hides a potential bug where the component won't render due to shallow comparison with the prev state which holds the same reference.

Refer to [Power Of Not Mutating Data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data).

```
duplicateEmployeeSource.push(duplicateItem);

// May not render the component because you mutated the state.
setEmployeeData(duplicateEmployeeSource);
```

Therefore, you need to generate a new key and change the state:

```
const duplicateEmployeeRow = async key => {
  const duplicateEmployeeSource = [...isEmployeeData];
  const duplicateItem = duplicateEmployeeSource.find(item => item.key === key);

  // or active the uuid() function
  duplicateItem.key = duplicateEmployeeSource.length;

  setEmployeeData(dup => [...dup, duplicateItem]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be finding an item from the array and putting it back into the array with the same key property and (as you know) if you are using this key to render DOM elements in a loop keys need to be unique.

You should use something more robust for production purposes but for testing using `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)` combined with the unique key prop from the cloned object should give you a pretty slim chance that multiple DOM elements will be rendered with the same key, unless you are cloning the same object many times.

```
const duplicateEmployeeRow = async key => {
  //not mutating so no need for a temp array
  let duplicateItem = isEmployeeData.find(item => item.key == key);
  duplicateItem.key = key + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) //better to use an actual unique identifier in production

  // use spread operator to avoid mutation and add new item
  setEmployeeData([...isEmployeeData , duplicateItem);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fixed it by getting the state of the key then add again by 1.
Also getting the fields that needs to be duplicated. Thanks for the suggestion using spread operator to avoid the mutation. Here's my final code.

```
let duplicateEmployeeSource = [...isEmployeeData];

let duplicateItem = duplicateEmployeeSource.find(item => item.key === key);

const count = state.isEmployeeRowKey;

  setState({
    ...state,
    isEmployeeRowKey: count + 1,
  });

  const payload = {
    key: state.isEmployeeRowKey,
    sfMember: duplicateItem.sfMember,
    leaveType: duplicateItem.leaveType,
    startDate: duplicateItem.startDate,
    startTime: duplicateItem.startTime,
    endDate: duplicateItem.endDate,
    endTime: duplicateItem.endTime,
  };

  setEmployeeData([...isEmployeeData, payload]); 
};
```